# Can "field“ used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

They succeed in persuading me to leave the field of technology in which I can easily find assurance in terms of job opportunity and financial stability.

Please tell me whether I can use the word "field" here. By “field” I mean a specific area of knowledge, can one say that one can find assurance of job opportunity in
an area of knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, field is fine.  But I would change "in which I can easily find assurance in terms of job opportunities and financial stability" to ", although I could have easily found job opportunities and financial stability."

Reasoning: 
-> Your phrasing "easily find assurance" is redundant; either "could have easily found" or "could have been assured of" are sufficient.
-> "in terms of" is wordy and is best left out.
-> since he convinced you to leave the field, the job and success are now what MIGHT have been; hence use "could have" rather than "can"